# Is this query safe to use? Prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is this query safe to use? I'm not sure how I'd convert it to a prepared statement as it's not using any values from the user:

```
$result = mysqli_query($cxn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $title = $row['title'];

  echo $title;
}
```

Is this safe to use? How can I improve it?

Thanks.

Comment: Why would one delete a comment saying this question ("is my query safe") too localized?

Comment: If you sanitized the `title` column when it was `INSERT`ed then the `$title` variable should be secure. If you did not then it may contain just about anything (i.e. HTML, Javascript, applets, Flash, etc.), which will be shown to the user. It is too simple to only think about the SQL query; the content itself can also be a problem if not sanitized properly.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen When you say "saved", you mean saved into the database right? In this case, I won't be putting anything into the database.

Comment: @John Yes, that is what I meant. Just make sure that the data in the database is actually safe. If it is not, or if you do not know, then it might be a good idea to throw it through something like  `htmlentities()` before outputting it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's safe. There is no user input used there at all; nothing that has the potential to mess up the query syntax or manipulate the outcome in any way.

As for improvements, there is no need to return every field in the table if you are only using the `title` field. In general, you should avoid the wild-card (`*`) for SELECT queries, except for testing purposes.

Also, the `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)` can be reduced to just `NOW() - INTERVAL 15 DAY`. Shorter and sweeter; no unnecessary function calls.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest improvement you can make is to change

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

to

```
SELECT title FROM table WHERE datetime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

because you are only using the `title` column in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is safe. It's best to use prepared statement if you decided to pass parameter to your sql.
here is example for you with parameter :

```
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = ?');
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
```

here is example/answer for your sql:

```
  $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        // do something with $row
    }
```

Comment: You still haven't really answered the question. It didn't involve any parameters at all.

Comment: @duskwuff I modified it again, would you please reconsider?

Comment: @CPU100: **Read the question.** The answer is words, not code.

Comment: @duskwuff I did attempt to answer it as "Yes it is safe" and also provided example of how to convert it to prepared statement. what would you like me to change?